# Why is this rsync + ssh cron job giving me 'Permission denied (publickey)' errors?

Tags: permissions, ssh, backup, cron, rsync

I make frequent backups to a local drive which I want to sync daily to a remote server.

The target server is configured for SSH key (no password) access only. Since my primary SSH key for that server is passphrase-protected, I've [created a second SSH key (not passphrase protected) + user to use for unattended backups](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503808/how-can-i-configure-a-second-ssh-key-user-for-a-single-server) - this way I do not have to be present to enter my passphrase when cron runs.

I'm using cron and rsync, and all of the commands work individually, but fail when combined.

The furthest I've got while troubleshooting is running

```
env -i sh -c "rsync -lrstRO --delete --exclude 'lost+found' /Backups/auto-daily-backups/./ backups-only@XX.XX.XX.XX:/backups/desktop/"
```

which returns the error

```
Permission denied (publickey).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]
```

**Any tips on how to troubleshoot this further?**

---

Here's what I've tried so far and I'm out of ideas:

1. Cron is definitely running `ps aux | grep cron`
2. Nothing unusual in /var/log/syslog `Sep  7 13:22:01 desktop CRON[6735]: (tom) CMD (sh /home/tom/Documents/Scripts/offsite-backup)`
3. SSH in Terminal to remote server as the backup user works `ssh backups-user@XX.XX.XX.XX`
4. Running the command in Terminal works perfectly `rsync -lrstRO --delete --exclude 'lost+found' /Backups/auto-daily-backups/./ backups-only@XX.XX.XX.XX:/backups/desktop/`
5. Manually specifying the path to the backups-user key has no effect `rsync -lrstRO --delete --exclude 'lost+found' -e 'ssh -i /home/tom/.ssh/backups-only' /Backups/auto-daily-backups/./ backups-only@XX.XX.XX.XX:/backups/desktop/`
6. Replacing the non-functioning command with a simple test command works `echo "Hello world" > ~/Desktop/test.txt`
7. Shouting/swearing at the computer had no effect (but made me feel better temporarily).

---

**Edit 1:**

Here's my crontab file and the script it calls.

```
...
# m h  dom mon dow   command
MAILTO=""
* * * * * sh /home/tom/Documents/Scripts/offsite-backup
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash

rsync -lrstRO --delete --exclude 'lost+found' /Backups/auto-daily-backups/./ backups-only@XX.XX.XX.XX:/backups/desktop/
```

---

**Edit 2:**

Just to clarify, `/var/log/auth.log` on the target server contains the line `Sep 11 08:23:01 <hostname> CRON[24421]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root` This is confusing because I'm no longer running cron every minute locally, but a new entry still appears every minute in the server logs. Crontab files for **all** users (including root) on the server are empty & do nothing.

Also, user 'backups-only' was created only on the server and with limited rights, with a dedicated SSH key copied to my desktop machine. I'm assuming this is the way to go because everything works when running the commands manually.

The crontab file posted above is for me, user 'tom' on my desktop machine. My intent is to have it call the script which should log in to the server as user 'backups-only'. I just tried running the backup script (rather than the command inside it) and it successfully connected & worked. I ran it on my desktop as user 'tom', same user who created the cron job that won't work. Here's the output from the server log corresponding with that successful login

```
Sep 11 08:35:31 <hostname> sshd[25071]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Sep 11 08:35:32 <hostname> sshd[25071]: Accepted publickey for backups-only from <desktop IP> port 54242 ssh2: RSA e2:e6:07:27:c1:continues...
Sep 11 08:35:32 <hostname> sshd[25071]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user backups-only by (uid=0)
Sep 11 08:35:32 <hostname> systemd-logind[638]: New session 12 of user backups-only.
Sep 11 08:36:00 <hostname> sshd[25133]: Received disconnect from <desktop IP>: 11: disconnected by user
Sep 11 08:36:00 <hostname> sshd[25071]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user backups-only
```

Comment: If 3. works using the keyfile and 6. works also, then... err... what does sshd logfile on the receiving end say?

Comment: @Jan I get `Sep  7 14:45:01 <hostname> CRON[18716]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root`

Comment: That's either the wrong log line or the user trying to connect via ssh is root...
Or is that from the machine that initiates the backups?

Comment: @Jan I'm running cron once a minute while I troubleshoot and that's the corresponding entry on the remote server. Shouldn't be root connecting as I specify 'backups-only@XX.XX.XX.XX'. Am I missing something basic?

Comment: So you're doing a push backup to a remote server, using the ssh user backups-only, initiated by cron. The cron on the source machine, I imagine.

The logline from the target machine should then start with "sshd", not "cron".

Comment: Example logline from my machine:
`Sep  7 16:06:02 <hostname> sshd[6747]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)`
In this case, my laptop connects to my server as root.

Comment: But you said you created a new user for the passwordless login, correct? so the cron job (or at least the ssh part of it) needs to run as that user surely?

Comment: Yes, it's a push from the local machine to the server. Root login is intentionally disabled in the server. I'm expecting to connect to it as the backups-only user from my local machine. This probably isn't happening (looks like cron is logging in as root?) and I need to have cron log in to the remote server as the backups-only user.

Comment: "ssh -i /home/tom/.ssh/backups-only -l backup-only XX.XX.XX.XX ls" work fine ?

Comment: Tom, 2 questions just to make sure  
In your first comment the logline has CRON[...], but it should look like `Sep 7 16:06:02 <hostname> sshd[6747]...`. Are you 100% positive that this logline is from the _server_ and that it is the correct line?

The crontab you posted is the crontab of _backups-only_?

Also, try to add the identity file manually: `rsync .... -e 'ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/identity' ...`

Comment: @Jan Thanks for the help so far, please see edit 2 above.

Comment: I'm sure the server executes a crontab somewhere. Did you also check `cron.d/`, `cron.daily/`, `cron.hourly/`, `cron.monthly/` and `cron.weekly/` in `/etc`?

Did you try to use `rsync .... -e 'ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/identity' `?

Comment: `cron.d/` and `cron.daily/` have nothing unusual, and nothing that runs every minute. I tried the `rsync ... -e 'ssh- i /Path/to/key` (documented in step 5 of my original question) & it didn't help.

Comment: Number 5, was that specifying the key only when you were trying through the terminal (number 4), or did you also change it in the script?

Comment: Also, that line in `auth.log` you posted under Edit 2 is for cron running on the server, and should have nothing to do with your login attempts. Can you try `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` on the server while you're trying to run the script through cron? Also, I'm not sure if this would work, but can you try your first `env` command with `rsync .... -e 'ssh -vvv -i /home/user/.ssh/identity ...` to see if it spits out more errors?

Comment: @AlaaAli Based on your suggestions it is now working. I used the full `env -i sh -c "rsync -lrstRO --delete --exclude 'lost+found' -e 'ssh -i /home/tom/.ssh/backups-only' /Backups/auto-daily-backups/./ backups-only@XX.XX.XX.XX:/backups/desktop/"` command in the script called by cron. Also, number 5 was tried in both Terminal & the script - no luck. And `auth.log` (plus successful transfer of the backup files) confirm this now works as expected. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it (& bounty) so thanks very much! Still don't understand it all but happy to have it working now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since everything is working fine from the command line, the error `Permission denied (publickey)` means that the SSH part of `rsync` is using a different identity file than the specified username.

From [Jan's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521142/why-is-this-rsync-ssh-cron-job-giving-me-permission-denied-publickey-error/524248#comment710972_521142) on the original question, we can specify the identity file in the `rsync` command using `-e 'ssh -i /path/to/identity.file' ...`.

Using the below command to start off with a fresh environment in cron and specifying the complete path to the file apparently solves the issue:

```
env -i sh -c "rsync -lrstRO --delete --exclude 'lost+found' -e 'ssh -i /home/tom/.ssh/backups-only' /Backups/auto-daily-backups/./ backups-only@XX.XX.XX.XX:/backups/desktop/"
```

<sub>I'm still really interested in this finding. It probably has to do with cron, the fact that it starts with minimal environment variables, and the ssh-agent. I'll be setting up the same scenario ina a couple of days to test it out and report back.</sub>

Comment: Do you mean you ran `env -i sh -c "rsync -lrstRO --delete --exclude 'lost+found' -e 'ssh -i /path/to/identity.file' /Backups/auto-daily-backups/./ backups-only@XX.XX.XX.XX:/backups/desktop/"`

Comment: @Problemania whops, fixed.

Comment: I see that you have an answer, but I'm curious are you running 'sudo crontab -e' that is the root cron. What happens if you 'crontab -e' while logged in as the "backup" user.

Comment: I think you meant this for the person that asked the question. But he was using his username's crontab, not root, and I think he didn't want to use the backup user's crontab.

Comment: when I run a similar script with my user, it takes the ssh key via X11, so I needed a local copy if key, and make sure this file has the correct owner and rights, combined with above worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just have solved this problem that has kept me busy ..

Unable to connect in RSYNC over SSH, despite having stipulated the identity for SSH ...Nothing is done ... 
***Rsync says "permission denied" and ssh tells me "read_passphrase: can not open /dev/tty: No device or address of this type"***

But I read a post that explained that the crontab has its own environment that is not the same as root. I already knew that but I did not understand the impact it could have on SSH when using the SSH-AGENT

But my SSH key exchanges are done with PassPhrase ... so if the environment is different and my RSYNC over SSH expects a passphrase that can not be entered => SSH debug info also indicate the error:

> "debug1: read_passphrase: can not open /dev/tty: No such device or
>   address"
>   => Well yes no TTY = no passphrase = not allowed

On my machine I use "Keychain" to have the SSH agent launched so I do not have to reenter the passphrase every time I try a remote connection. Keychain generates a file that contains the following information

> SSH_AUTH_SOCK = /tmp/ssh-PWg3yHAARGmP/agent.18891;  export
>   SSH_AUTH_SOCK; SSH_AGENT_PID = 18893;  export SSH_AGENT_PID;

==> The SSH-AGENT command returns the same info.

So, in the end, it is these information related to the current session that allow future authentications of the current session, without the need to enter the passphrase because already done previously and memorized ...

**==> The solution is there ...** it is enough in the script launched by the crontab, and to "source" the file containing this information or to do it on the command line ds the crontab ...

> example: 14 09 * * *. /home/foo/.keychain/foo.serveur.org-sh && scp
>   -vvv -P 22 /tmp/mon_fic/toto.sh foo@my-server.fr :. >> / var / log / check_connexion.log 2> & 1 or use the command "source
>   /home/foo/keychain/foo.server.org-sh" in the script that starts a
>   connection using SSH.

=> With this sourcing, no more worry. The information of SSH_AUTH_SOCK and SSH_AGENT_PID are loaded in the environment of the Crontab and are therefore known, the RSYNC over SSH works without any problem.

It has kept me busy but now, it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Caveat for those who use SSH Agent Forwarding:

If you see this behaviour when debugging a script on a remote host, it's because even with the `-e "ssh -i /path/to/key"` flag, ssh will use your local (forwarded) key rather than the one on the server.

Concrete example: I have a script on the dev server that pulls in data from the "data server" using rsync over ssh. When I log into the dev server and run it, all is well, but when running from cron, I get the permission denied. Adding some verbosity to the SSH process (flag `-vv`) I noticed the following:

```
debug2: key: /home/nighty/.ssh/id_rsa (0x562d8b974820),
debug2: key: /home/juanr/.ssh/id_rsa (0x562d8b962930), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/nighty/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 1a:19:08:9f:80:16:b1:db:55:42:9a:52:b2:49:9b:0a
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

What clued me off here is that by pure chance, I happen to have a different username on the local host ("nighty") than on the dev server ("juanr").

Notice how it marks the key on the dev server as "explicit", but still uses the forwarded key from my laptop to log in. Doing an `ssh-copy-id` at this point resolves nothing, because it simply reinstalls the forwarded key rather than the one from the dev server. If you use ssh-copy-id with agent forwarding, you need to specify which key to install with the -i flag: `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@host`.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but I had the same issue. Local user `crontab -l` showed my daily backup task:

```
  0   5   *    *    5    /repos/local-bin/backup-backups daily-6
```

Worked when I called `/repos/local-bin/backup-backups daily-6` directly. Worked when I called the underlying `rsync` command by itself. Worked when I `ssh`-ed into the systems I was attempting to back up. `ssh-add -l` showed my environment's agent/keychain had the keys I needed stored properly and readily available.

So, following the advice of the main answer, I added `env` to `/repos/local-bin/backup-backups`, made the cron task run immediately, copied the output from `env`, added `export` before each of the lines, opened up a new terminal, ran `env -i sh`, and pasted the `export` commands into it. Then I ran my `ssh` command from earlier and it failed. Finally! I noticed that the cron environment was receiving a pid for an ssh agent, though, so it should be working...

I ran `ssh-add -l`, saw that the latest SSH keys I created weren't added to this environment's agent/keychain... but some of my other keys were?? Which is weird, because it was working with the agent I was using outside of this environment... oh wait! I'm using KDE's wallet/agent outside of this (my desktop) environment, and using ssh-agent directly inside of this environment (my terminal environment)! So I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to drop out of KDE, ran `ssh-add -l`, saw that it, too, was missing the keys I needed, and ran my `add-ssh-keys` script. Normally this is done automatically around boot/login time, but these were newly minted SSH keys that needed to be added to both my KDE keychain (which I had done properly) *and my non-KDE ssh-agent* (which I forgot to do). Hopefully this helps someone else avoid a few hours of hair pulling :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried the old trick of cleaning up the hosts files? 
I mean:

```
rm ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

It's worth trying as ssh will rebuild it and you will get rid of stale stuff. You can of course also remove the parts belonging to a given IP / Host.

More questions: Is your cron job running under your UID or is it running as user cron or root?

Comment: The commands each work individually, so I don't see how deleting `~/.ssh/known_hosts` would change anything? And cron runs as my user 'tom' on the desktop, with the intention of logging in to the server as user 'backups-only' with that corresponding (passwordless) SSH key, which is in user tom's `~/.ssh`.

Comment: @runlevel0 Neither the `-r` nor the `-f` flag is needed to delete `known_hosts`--it's a regular file (not a directory), and it is not readonly. `rm .ssh/known-hosts` would be considerably safer, considering that a single-character typo--accidentally adding a space between `.` and `ssh/known_hosts` after `rm -rf` (or `rm -r`) would usually delete the entire contents of the user's home folder!

Comment: Hi Eliah, excellent point indeed!!
I use the -rf flag as a reflex action, but you are absolutely right. Me bad.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `rrsync` script together with a dedicated ssh key as follows:

REMOTE server

```
mkdir ~/bin
gunzip /usr/share/doc/rsync/scripts/rrsync.gz -c > ~/bin/rrsync
chmod +x ~/bin/rrsync
```

LOCAL computer

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_remote_backup -C "Automated remote backup"      #NO passphrase
scp ~/.ssh/id_remote_backup.pub devel@10.10.10.83:/home/devel/.ssh
```

REMOTE computer

```
cat id_remote_backup.pub >> authorized_keys
```

Prepend to the newly added line the following

```
command="$HOME/bin/rrsync -ro ~/backups/",no-agent-forwarding,no-port-forwarding,no-pty,no-user-rc,no-X11-forwarding
```

So that the result looks like

```
command="$HOME/bin/rrsync -ro ~/backups/",no-agent-forwarding,no-port-forwarding,no-pty,no-user-rc,no-X11-forwarding ssh-rsa AAA...vp Automated remote backup
```

LOCAL

Put in your `crontab` the following script with `x` permission:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo ""
echo ""
echo "CRON:" `date`
set -xv
rsync -e "ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_remote_backup" -avzP devel@10.10.10.83:/ /home/user/servidor
```

Source: http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2014/01/14/restricting-ssh-access-to-rsync/

Answer (score 0):

To try and debug add to the ssh part "ssh -v" this way you can get verbose mode with some helpful information.

**Edit:** From the man page:

```
-v      Verbose mode.  Causes ssh to print debugging messages about its progress.  This is helpful in debugging connection,
             authentication, and configuration problems.  Multiple -v options increase the verbosity.  The maximum is 3.
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you haven't configured the sshd_config file properly. Verify that `PermitRootLogin yes` and `PubkeyAuthentication yes`  for remote maintenance.

Comment: He's not trying to login as root, and he probably has public key authentication setup correctly because he can ssh and even run the backup command from the terminal successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I definitely do not have `PermitRootLogin` enabled and have no plans to change that. Best practice is to disable it, and ssh only as a normal user (add them to your 'sudoers' if necessary) and never as root.