# rsync + ssh public key asking authentication

Tags: ssh, backup, authentication, rsync

After creating the keys and use `ssh-copy-id` command successfully, I can connect by `ssh user@host` but when I'm trying to do a transfer via rsync and it asks for password... rsync command is as follows:

```
rsync -av -e "ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes -o PasswordAuthentication=no -X user@hostname" /home/Compart user@hostname:/home/user/backup/
```

I already tried:

```
rsync -av --rsh="ssh -l user" /home/Compart user@hostname:/home/user/backup/
rsync -av -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" /home/Compart user@hostname:/home/user/backup/
```

and still nothing... always asks for a password...

```
#tail -f /var/log/auth.log
Oct 27 11:48:42 hostname sshd[15531]: Accepted password for user from 10.14.6.93 port 41893 ssh2
Oct 27 11:48:42 hostname sshd[15531]: pam_group(sshd:setcred): bad group: powerdev
Oct 27 11:48:42 hostname sshd[15531]: pam_group(sshd:setcred): bad group: libvirt
Oct 27 11:48:42 hostname sshd[15531]: pam_group(sshd:setcred): bad group: kvm
Oct 27 11:48:42 hostname sshd[15531]: pam_group(sshd:setcred): bad group: sane
Oct 27 11:48:42 hostname sshd[15531]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Oct 27 11:48:42 hostname systemd-logind[879]: New session 39 of user user.
Oct 27 11:48:42 hostname sshd[15615]: pam_group(sshd:setcred): bad group: powerdev
Oct 27 11:48:42 hostname sshd[15615]: pam_group(sshd:setcred): bad group: libvirt
Oct 27 11:48:42 hostname sshd[15615]: pam_group(sshd:setcred): bad group: kvm
Oct 27 11:48:42 hostname sshd[15615]: pam_group(sshd:setcred): bad group: sane
Oct 27 11:48:42 hostname sshd[15615]: Received disconnect from 10.14.6.93: 11: disconnected by user
Oct 27 11:48:42 hostname sshd[15531]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user user
Oct 27 11:48:54 hostname systemd-logind[879]: Removed session 39.
```

Where 10.14.6.93 is the machine where the files are right now and where the rsync is being executed...

any ideas?

Comment: Use `... -e "ssh -i /path/to/private-key ..."` to make sure SSH is using the key. Take a look at this question if it helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/521142/why-is-this-rsync-ssh-cron-job-giving-me-permission-denied-publickey-error

Comment: I'v read this post and tried some procedures sugested there but nothing worked. I'll try the -e "ssh -i /path/to/private-key" as soon as I have access to the pc...

Answer (score 0):

The following command uses my pubkey and does not ask for a password even though I have both a valid password and valid pubkey for the remote host.  Also make sure you don't have a password set in `.ssh/config` just to be safe.

`rsync -av /home/user user@hostname:/home/user/backup`

Comment: I have no config at ~/.ssh/ and using the command the way you said still asks for password