# Backup with rsync works but not in crontab

Tags: cron, rsync

Using this command in rsync:

```
rsync -azvh pi@192.168.1.45:/media/PNY/video /home/john/Desktop/Pi\ Videos
```

Works flawlessly. Now, when I put this command in crontab to run every 15 minutes, it does not work and I am wondering if my command in crontab is correct?

```
*/15 * * * * rsync -avzhe ssh pi@192.168.1.45:/media/PNY/video /home/john/Desktop/Pi\ Videos
```

Comment: I myself would use a script inside crontab and have that script hold this command. That way you can easily add a redirect to show the error you face. As a pointer: does your cron know where "rsync" resides on your system since you omitted the directory ;-)

Comment: I'll let you know the outcome. Thanks Rinzwind.

Comment: I'm beginning to think I've got a permissions issue but not sure how to fix it. I can run the script file with no errors but as soon as I put it into the crontab, it fails. <code>*/5 * * * * bash /home/john/rsyncpi.sh >> /home/john/crontestlog.log 2>&1</code>  I invoked a copy to a log file and here is the output of that. <code>Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).</code> I took out the ssh and ran it but it still fails.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wow, What a dig! I found the answer on [linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/rsync-doesn't-work-with-crontab-4175545095/)

CLI and crontab run on different environments. Crontab needs to be told where the private key is. I followed the instructions on the link and simply added the location of private key on the command and it worked. The previous command now has this addition added.

```
*/15 * * * * rsync -avzhe "ssh -i /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa_dvr.pi" pi@192.168.1.45:/media/PNY/video /home/john/Desktop/Pi\ Videos
```

Now on to find a doctor that can help get some of these roots put back in. :-)

Comment: I had the same issue and was able to remedy it by specifying the location of the identity file in `~/.ssh/config`. See **man ssh_config** for more info

Answer (score 1):

I suppose without parameters there is no need to use "-e" and "ssh" option in the scheduled command. Please try it plain:

```
*/15 * * * * rsync -avzh pi@192.168.1.45:/media/PNY/video /home/john  /Desktop/Pi\ Videos
```

Comment: I did try it without the ssh and it worked from terminal but I am still not able to do this through crontab.

Comment: Hi Laserman, please check the permissions of the home directory of the remote user pi@192.168.1.45 and especially /home/pi/.ssh directory. It should be 700, thus only user-writeable. This may be preventing you from logging in using pubkey, as in crontab, but is going good via ssh.

Comment: I checked both server and client and they are set to permissions 700. Still no luck.

Comment: I found a post that mentions a similar error I received on a log file. http://askubuntu.com/questions/521142/why-is-this-rsync-ssh-cron-job-giving-me-permission-denied-publickey-error I'm not sure how to add it to my application and invoke an identify command.